error : UNREACHABLE executed!This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way
While funning doxyfile file I'm getting an error : UNREACHABLE executed!This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way, When I'm parsing the .cpp in Input. It was working fine before after updating Visual studio 2022, it is working fine
I expect it to working fine as before

Which version of doxygen are you using? What happens when you run doxygen outside of Visual Studio? The sentence "It was working fine before after updating Visual studio 2022, it is working fine" is confusing what do you mean? All in all it looks like the plugin(?) used in VS is not working properly anymore.

Doxygen version is 1.8.6.
What happens when you run doxygen outside of Visual Studio? >> it doesn't generate the .chm file as expected.
"It was working fine before after updating Visual studio 2022, it is working fine" >> before updating VS2022 we were able to generate helpfile (.chm).
When we are passing the .cpp file encountering the error else doxygen is working fine

Doxygen version is 1.8.6 is quite old (December 24, 2013) the current doxygen version is 1.10.0 Please show what you tried outside VS Studio 2022 and also the difference in the settings from the default doxygen setting (in the newer versions the result of: doxygen -x Doxyfile) and mention these results in the question.
